# Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology : Topology activation failed during attemt to fix degraded index

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, search, index-component

Im trying to fix a degraded index, using the script from this post. [How do I fix a degraded SharePoint 2013 index partition when there is only one of them?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88697/how-do-i-fix-a-degraded-sharepoint-2013-index-partition-when-there-is-only-one-o)

But the last line Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -identity $clone, resultes in this error:

```
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology : Topology activation failed. Management called failed with System.InvalidOperationExcep
tion: 'Unable to change topology when Generation controller is not active' at    at Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.IndexCon
troller.IndexController.IsEmptyIndex(String indexSystemName)
   at Microsoft.Ceres.SearchCore.IndexController.IndexControllerManagementAgent.WrapCall[T](Func`2 original)
At E:\recreatesearch.ps1:27 char:1
+ Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -identity $clone
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Offic...tSearchTopology:SetSearchTopology) [Set-SPEnterpriseSear
   chTopology], SearchTopologyActivationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Cmdlet.SetSearchTopology
```

This means i'm not able to fix the degraded index. And im left with the option of resetting the index. I would like to avoid this by any chance, because its estimated to take 4-5 weeks to complete.

Do anyone have any tricks i might try.

I already tried: reset confic cache, restart search host, restart search server, reboot the server itself.

Comment: Is any of the search components down/degraded? And do you have a link to the post that you mention?

Comment: I added link to the post. just as in the post (How do I fix a degraded...) the indexComponent is degraded. I create a clone and replace the index component with a new one. But unlike the post, my Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -identity $clone call failes with the mentioned error.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you won't be able to avoid an index reset or a re-crawl.

I'm not a search expert and have only cloned a search topology once but it seem's that all the search components need to be in a healthy state to be able to clone them, otherwise you would only clone a topology that is still broken and would be stuck with the same problem.

[SharePoint 2013 Unable to change topology when Generation controller is not active](http://blogs.technet.com/b/peter_dempsey/archive/2013/04/11/sharepoint-2013-unable-to-change-topology-when-generation-controller-is-not-active.aspx)

If you had multiple topologys where you had at least one component that were healthy, it could have been possible to clone that one.

Here's a thread where a member of this forum tried this, sadly without success so he had to recreate the search service application from scratch.

[Create new Index Component and add it to a clone topology?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/81198/create-new-index-component-and-add-it-to-a-clone-topology)